# Unable to edit xml file through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have been trying to edit an xml file through python for last 4-5 hours but i am unable to do so .

the xml file encoding is "windows-1252"

my main intent is to change port 2/5 to 2/1  and 2/8 to 2/4,

i want to change following 4 attributes in this xml file

```
Location="//10.22.12.5/2/5"
Name="Port //2/5"
Location="//10.22.12.5/2/8"
Name="Port //2/8"
```

i wrote following code for this but i am unable to change the xml file :

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('pathtofilename.xml')

    for elem in tree.findall('.//id'):
        assert elem.attrib['Location'] == "//10.22.12.5/2/5"
        elem.attrib['Location'] = "//10.22.12.5/2/1"

    for elem in tree.findall('.//id'):
        assert elem.attrib['Location'] == "//10.22.12.5/2/8"
        elem.attrib['Location'] = "//10.22.12.5/2/4"

with open('pathtooutput.xml', 'wb') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, encoding='windows-1252'))
```

xml file parameters which i want to change is having this format:

```
[![<Port id="2645" 
     Location="//10.22.12.5/2/5"
     UseDefaultHost="TRUE"
     AppendLocationToPortName="TRUE"
     Layer3Type="IPV4"
     PortGroupSize="1"
     TestModuleProfile="Default"
     IsFlexEthernetPort="FALSE"
     IsFlexEthernetPhy="FALSE"
     IsFlexEthernetClient="FALSE"
     IsPgaPort="TRUE"
     Active="TRUE"
     LocalActive="TRUE"
     Name="Port //2/5">


<Port id="2646" 
     Location="//10.22.12.5/2/8"
     UseDefaultHost="TRUE"
     AppendLocationToPortName="TRUE"
     Layer3Type="IPV4"
     PortGroupSize="1"
     TestModuleProfile="Default"
     IsFlexEthernetPort="FALSE"
     IsFlexEthernetPhy="FALSE"
     IsFlexEthernetClient="FALSE"
     IsPgaPort="TRUE"
     Active="TRUE"
     LocalActive="TRUE"
     Name="Port //2/8">][1]][1]
```

> Please find link to xml file :

https://github.com/sen2diwakar/python_coding/blob/master/file.xml

Comment: Is there any data changed in output xml file compared to input xml

Comment: no man ! nothing changed ! can you tell me how to attach xml here

Comment: https://github.com/sen2diwakar/python_coding/blob/master/file.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code `tree.findall('.//id')` it's returning empty list. Because there is no tag with name `id`. You should use tag `Port` to find the elment you want to update.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse('test.txt')

location = ["//10.22.12.5/2/5", "//10.22.12.5/2/8"]
new_location = ["//10.22.12.5/2/1", "//10.22.12.5/2/4"]
new_port = ["Port //2/1", "Port //2/4"]


for idx, x in enumerate(location):
    elmt = root.find('//Port[@Location="{}"]'.format(x))
    elmt.attrib['Location'] = new_location[idx]
    elmt.attrib['Name'] = new_port[idx]


with open('pathtooutput.xml', 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding='windows-1252'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = utils.getFileContent("pathtofilename.xml",encoding="windows-1252") # Open file

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
port = doc.select('Port#2645')
port.setAttrs({"Location":"//10.22.12.5/2/1", "Name":"Port //2/1"}) # Change attributes

utils.saveFile("pathtooutput.xml",doc.html, encoding="windows-1252") # Save flie
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<Port id="2645" Location="//10.22.12.5/2/1" UseDefaultHost="TRUE" AppendLocationToPortName="TRUE" Layer3Type="IPV4" PortGroupSize="1" TestModuleProfile="Default" IsFlexEthernetPort="FALSE" IsFlexEthernetPhy="FALSE" IsFlexEthernetClient="FALSE" IsPgaPort="TRUE" Active="TRUE" LocalActive="TRUE" Name="Port //2/1"></Port>
```